# build and install r package from github repository under Windows

Tags: r

I would like to build an R package from a github repository for an older version of R:

https://github.com/suiji/Arborist/

The R package is actually Rborist, so not sure whether to clone the whole repo mentioned above?

I installed Rtools after miserably failing to run:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("https://github.com/suiji/Arborist/tree/master/Rborist/src")
```

or:

library(devtools)
install_github("suiji/Arborist")

What do I have to do to build this package please?

Comment: The package has a very uncommon structure, which is why `devtools` won't work. There is an `.sh` script which seems to build the package and then you can install it from the tarball. TBH I doubt that this will be easy under windows.

Comment: Did you read the instructions in the Readme?  If you have a compatible version of Rtools, you should be able to install a CRAN version from source using `install.packages("Rborist", type="source")` as long as your R is at version 3.3 or better.

Comment: Thanks I will try this!